# How to make a one to one eloquent relation in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I created my migration by using the artisan command

```
php artisan make:model Player -m
```

My migration then looked like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('players', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete$
        $table->string('username');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Which left me no errors when I ran

```
php artisan migrate
```

I then updated my Player model `App/Player.php` to include the fillables and one to one relation

```
class Player extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'username'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

I then ran the Tinker artisan and my output when I try to access the player model is this

```
>>> User::find(1)->player;
=> null
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you done the reverse connection?

Here is the Relation Code

```
public function player() 
{
 return $this->hasOne(Player::class);  
}
```

Comment: I do not think so, what I put in my question is all I have done

Comment: public function player()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Player');
    }
}

Comment: Or Something along those line

Answer (score 0):

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id' */foreign_key */ ,'user_id'*/owner_key*/);
}
```

i think you forgot to specify the owner_id,
if you dont specify the owner_key of belongsTo the default belongsTo getting is the model id.

Answer (score 0):

User Model

```
public function player(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Player');
}
```

Player Model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```